# how to fixed sending message with gsm modem in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sms

I use gsm modem for sending message in winform application. but after a few months, modem dose not worked and did not send a message. i change modem and a few months use it's, but An error occurred again.
how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> Kylix modem

and send message. this is very good modem for sendeng message.